# Why Bt709 have 2 different conversion from RGB to YCbCr , which coefficients should we use?

Tags: rgb, yuv

the Screenshots of BT709 is as follows:
[image]

Comment: None of them? You do not see a RGB to YCC conversion, but signal levels. I think you are looking the wrong table. In any case, you should get the same results.

Comment: Thanks , the doc is from BT709-3,   I really do not know why there have 2 different conversion, maybe there is 2 different color gamut of scan-1125 and scan-1250 ??

Comment: But this is about the signal strength, not about colours. If I remember correctly the colorometry data are in an other section (maybe just on base BT709). So I assume you will have the same colours, just with different signal strength, which a TV should in any case normalize). Your BT709 seems an annex for new picture format.